# How to get frame id from background to content script?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(receiver);
function receiver(request, sender, sendResponse);
```

The message listener runs more than once because the application has a frame. I want to get the frame id from background script and pass it to the content script so that if the frame matches I would pass message to the pop up script.

```
function getXPath(info, tab) {
    var msg = {
        subject: "getXPath"
    };
    var inspectedId = tab.id;
    var selectedFrameId = info.frameId;
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(inspectedId, msg, { frameId: selectedFrameId });
}
```

Using the `info`, I am able to get the frame id, but I don't know how to pass it to the content script.

Comment: You can pass it inside your `msg` by adding a property like `frameId: info.frameId`.

Comment: yea, but how do I check if listener is running for that frame ?

Comment: Assuming you [declared "all_frames": true](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#frames), each frame will be running an instance of your content script. If this doesn't help you, add more details to your question because currently it's unclear what exactly you're doing, what your manifest.json is, how it all runs and so on.

Comment: In manifest i have declared:
`"run_at": "document_start",
  "all_frames": true,`
so that I can get the html element in all the frames. After getting the element I am building XPath with it.
Problem is after generating the XPath, it must pass to the pop up page.
It works fine if the document is not inside the frame, When the doc is inside the frame the listener ran that many times based on the frame, So if I can identify the frame id in content script I can rectify that.
This is my extension:
[link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/r%C5%ABto/ilcoelkkcokgeeijnopjnolmmighnppp)

Comment: From background I am able to get the frame id using the info, and also can pass it using msg Object, but how can I can check in `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(senderM);
function senderM(request, sender, sendResponse){ }`
// here sender is passing only the extension ID not the frame Id.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I understand how your extension workflow is organized but I think you can simply send a `getMyFrameId` message from the content script to the background script, which will do `sendResponse(sender.frameId)` that you will save in your content script's global variable, and then use it.

Comment: OK thank you. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

finally **Solved**, 
Each and every frame has unique document by comparing the document object I am to achieve it.